# Style sheet changes font size but not color?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Ruby on Rails app, using the bootstrap gem and a local stylesheet. At present, navbar menu items are gray and turn white on hover. I want them to turn black on hover, because the bar background is white.

After trying many things, I am now looking at something even simpler: just make a single link black. I have attached a class to the link as such:

```
<li><%= link_to "Home", root_path, { :class => 'top_menu_item'} %></li>
```

Then, in the local stylesheet, which is the last one loaded, I have:

```
.top_menu_item {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: black;
}
```

This correctly changes the font size of the link, which I put in just to check everything is working, but the color stays gray? I'm guessing I have the syntax wrong, but not wrong enough to cause an error?

A pointer to a good resource on using bootstrap within Ruby on Rails would also be good for the longer term. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably due to specificity. When you use the development tools, you can check if your CSS is overwritten by another rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link style gets overwritten by one of the bootstrap styles out there. Options:

- Find the bootstrap style and change it (use the console to track the style chain)
- Specify the target style more thoroughly, as in: `li a.top_menu_item { color: black; }` instead of what you have now.
- Use `!important` on your setting, as in: `color: black !important` I **don't** recommend this and you should only do it when all else fails, but sometimes you need to get stuff done.

Read more about style priorities [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/).

Comment: Thanks. As per the comment I made above, !important fixes the immediate problem. Now I'll look into the other suggestions to try and solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Great, if you find the answer helpful I'd appreciate it if you could mark it as a solution. Good luck coding!

Comment: As stated in the answer, it cannot be emphasized enough: The usage of `!important` is **highly** discouraged. You should try all other thinkable solutions first before **ever** applying `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below..

```
.top_menu_item {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: black !important;
}

.top_menu_item a{
  color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Adding the !important, as per your first class, fixed it. Thank you! I then got the hover behaviour I was looking for with:

`.top_menu_item {
  &:hover {
    color: black !important;
  }
}`

Comment: The usage of `!important` is **highly** discouraged. You should try all other thinkable solutions first before **ever** applying `!important`.